# How to properly handle dynamic forms using react hooks useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I properly manage the state for this [particular UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7jkm.png)- form where the user can add an input field (add input button) and add an input section (add section button).

I'm thinking that this would be my initial state, where I could map each array object to be input section and each params array to be the number of input.

```
const [values, setValue] = useState([
  {
    params: ['1 input']
  },
  {
    params: ['2 input','2 input']
  }
])
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to add value to params array, how do I pass my initial state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [values, setValue] = useState([
    {
      params: ["1 input"]
    },
    {
      params: ["2 input", "2 input"]
    }
  ]);

  const createInputHelper = index => {
    const stateCopy = values;
    stateCopy[index].params.concat(`{index + 1} input`);
    setValue(stateCopy);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", width: "100px" }}>
        {values.map((value, firstIndex) => {
          return value.params.map((param, index) => {
            return (
              <input
                value={param}
                onClick={() => createInputHelper(firstIndex)}
              />
            );
          });
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

basically you are updating the values on some event, e.g. when clicking the button
so you need to catch that event, and when it triggers, you update your data, and then use `setValues()`

```
function handleOnClick(input){
  const updatedValues = [...values];
  updatedValues[0].params.push(input)
  setValue(updatedValues);
}
```